# Shell Sort program

Tags: c, sorting

I am not an expert on sorting but from what I understood, the following program should work. Unfortunately, it doesn't always work. Can you please help me figure out what is wrong with it? Thanks. The following is the code:

```
/*
* Question4.c
*
*  Created on: 12 Feb 2015
*      Author: Daniel
*/

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10

int main(void)
{

    int array[SIZE], i, gap,temp, k, m;

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        array[i] = rand();
    }
    for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    gap = SIZE/2;
    k=0;
    while(gap!=1) {
        gap = gap/2;
        k++;
    }
    m=k;
    gap = (SIZE)/2;
    k=0;
    while(k!=m+1) {
        for (i=gap; i<SIZE; i++) {
            if (array[i-gap]>array[i]) {
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i-gap];
                array[i-gap] = temp;
            }
        }
        gap = (int)(gap  / 2);
        k++;
    }
    for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't always work"?  Please show a sample input, the expected output, and the output you're getting.

Comment: For example, input: 13288 26778 19512 30385 10233 12279 31398 4112 22303 29945; output: 4112 10233 13288 12279 19512 22303 26778 30385 29945 31398

Comment: What's the sorting algorithm you use here ?

Comment: @KcDoD I am using Shell Sort

Comment: Try to find a smaller input set that fails, then step through with the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is incorrect. The part where you do the sorting is only using one pass, but it needs to be a complete insertion sort or bubble sort. In other words, this:

```
for (i=gap; i<SIZE; i++) {
    if (array[i-gap]>array[i]) {
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[i-gap];
        array[i-gap] = temp;
    }
}
```

Needs to be: (this is the insertion sort variant)

```
for (i=gap; i<SIZE; i++) {
    int j;
    temp = a[i];
    for (j=i; j >= gap && a[j-gap] > temp; j-=gap)
        a[j] = a[j-gap];
    a[j] = temp;
}
```

You can make a bubble sort variant too.  But you definitely need a second `for` loop instead of what you currently have.